# how to test a model that has a foreign key in django?

Tags: django, django-tests

I'm using python 3.5 and Django 1.10 and trying to test my app in tests.py, but an error appeared, it said: `ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "NewsLetter.UserID" must be a "User" instance.` so how to test a fk value here?
here is the code:

```
class NewsletterModelTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        #Set up non-modified objects used by all test methods
        NewsLetter.objects.create(NewsLetterID=1, Email='test@test.com', Connected=False,UserID=1)


    class NewsLetter(models.Model):
         NewsLetterID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
         Email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
         Connected = models.BooleanField(default=False)
         UserID = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         class Meta:
              db_table = 'NewsLetter'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your `setupTestData` method you have to create a `User` object, and pass it into the `NewsLetter` object `create` method.

```
@classmethod
def setUpTestData(cls):
    #Set up non-modified objects used by all test methods
    user = User.objects.create(<fill params here>)
    NewsLetter.objects.create(NewsLetterID=1, Email='test@test.com', Connected=False,UserID=user)
```

Comment: the thing is user also has more than one fk field, so does this mean I have to add model.objects.create to all models I will use in every class?

Comment: you have to create the object first to pass it to any class that has fk field. There is no other way around this

Answer (score 4):

For those who land here.

To write a test for a model that has a ForeignKey field, you need to create an instance of the model that the ForeignKey points to **and then call save() on the ForeignKey instance**, before applying it to the creation of your target model for the test.

eg. (simplified for brevity)

```
class BookTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_fields_author_name(self):
        author = Author(name="Mazuki Sekida")
        author.save()
        book = Book(name="Zen Training", author=author)
        book.save()

        # assertion example ...
        record = Book.objects.get(id=1)
        self.assertEqual(record.author.name, "Mazuki Sekida")
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to what @Arpit Solanki answered, here's what I did:

```py
from datetime import date

from django.test import TestCase

from ..models import Post, Author


class PostModelTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.author_ = 'Rambo'
        cls.author = Author.objects.create(name=cls.author_)
        cls.post = Post.objects.create(
            title='A test', author=cls.author, content='This is a test.', date=date(2021, 6, 16))

    def test_if_post_has_required_author(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.post.author.name, self.author_)
```